# User posted a question to get a link. Is that allowed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have seen this question

- [How do I download a binary file over HTTP using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11110887/1065197).

And the user commented "I was hoping to a link of some kind of httpclient get tutorial, thanks". Are this kind of questions allowed in the community? In case not, what kind of flag should I use for that question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, a bit on our policy on links: Link only answers aren't allowed--you must give atleast a concise explanation of the link contents.

Now, we aren't one of those quick fix fora. We will *not* Google stuff for you, or just solve every problem you fling at us.

Also, it doesn't show what he's tried, another feature of quick-fix fora that we want to avoid.

We want to Make The Internet Better™, so questions should garner nice, conceptual answers that will help future visitors.

Yes, it doesn't fall under any of the close,reasons, but NARQ is reasonably close if it's asking for something huge (unless the huge thing can be linked to *and summarized*).

Comment: Note that the "iffy" NARQ was for the general case. This specific case is NARQ anyway, due to a bunch of things (LMGTFY, What Have You Tried, etc)

Answer (score 10):

It's not a real question to me.

- If the user is only looking for a link, Google is available (and many responders would use it)
- It doesn't convey any previous attempts at solving the problem
- It doesn't seem like it would be of anyone's benefit in the future; if the answer only really contained a link, then given enough time, that link would be useless